# ERROR: Unknown connection option in connection string: attachdbfilename

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

Cant seem to get my connection string to work.

app.config file:

```
<add name="PalisadeWorld.Properties.Settings.PalisadeWorldDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PalisadeWorldDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Where I use the connection string:

```
  SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\\Users\\Win8User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010'Projects\\PalisadeWorld\\PalisadeWorld\\PalisadeWorldDatabase.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

I've tried almost everything I could think of or find online.

I keep getting the error:

> Unknown connection option in connection string: attachdbfilename.

Am I missing something?

Thank your for you time

Comment: The `AttachDbFileName=` features works **ONLY** on SQL Server **EXPRESS** - not on any other editions. Are you sure you're connecting to a SQL Server Express edition?

Comment: [Here is a good helper](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: for SqlCeConnection you have to set the path for the sdf in the connection string only

Comment: @marc_s Indeed I am sure.

Comment: @marc_s +1, I am connecting to a SQL Server Express edition, however my error lies along the same line, silly me:) thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was not using the compact version of SQL (`SqlCeConnect`)

so I need to use `SqlConnect` instead

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\PalisadeWorldDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Thanks everyone, Kindly

Answer (score 0):

Template for connection string is

```
<add name="TrempimModel"
 connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
                   database=YourDatabaseName;
                   AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
                   User Instance=true"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

please remove '\' from the attachdbfilename attibute after datadirectoy so new connectionstring will be

```
<add name="PalisadeWorldDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|PalisadeWorldDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and when getting connection string use.

```
 SqlCeConnection Con = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PalisadeWorldDatabaseConnectionString"].ToString());
```