# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' when Integrated Security=false - Why try to create a database that already exists?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I have an ASP.net MVC app connecting to (localdb)\v11.0 SQL Server database with a connection string using "Integrated Security" - works fine.

Now I want to connect to the same db with a User ID & PW.

I created the login & user:  user100, gave it db_owner permission.
I can open the db with that ID/PW using SSMS.

But when I change my connection string to "User ID=user100 & Password=xxxx", I get the error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.\r\nCannot
>   attach the file
>   'C:\Projects\ExcellerWeb\ExcellerWeb\App_Data\ExcellerWebCopy.mdf'
>   as database 'ExcellerWebCopy'.

Why does it try to create a database that already exists?

And the following code returns TRUE:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists("UserConnection");
```

At first I thought it was EF Migrations, but it seems to happen on a simple test project without Migrations.

Here's my connection string:

```
<add name="UserConnection"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ExcellerWeb.mdf;Initial Catalog=ExcellerWeb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user200; Password=****"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Option `AttachDbFilename` from your connectionstring.

```
<add name="UserConnection"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ExcellerWeb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user200; Password=****"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This option is there to attach the file when you open the connection.
For more details have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832827/error-unknown-connection-option-in-connection-string-attachdbfilename) or this [MSDN-article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the original question, but we got the same error message when we moved a web app and database to new hardware, and a Google search led me here, so hopefully this might help someone...

In our case, the connection string that the web app used was fine, and the database already existed, so the error message was a bit of a surprise.

The problem turned out to be that the service account running the app pool in IIS didn't have the correct permissions on the database - when the account was added to the appropriate group, everything worked fine.